# How to setup GoDaddy SSL on Ubuntu (with Webmin)?

Tags: apache-2.2, ubuntu, ssl, https

I use Webmin to manage an Ubuntu 10.10 server and have a VirtualHost setup (and working) for http://mydomain.com. If I want to install an SSL certificate from a CA like GoDaddy (already generated a CSR), how do I set it up in Webmin? Would I just create another Vhost with the same document root but have it listen on *:443?

Are there any special directives I'd need to add to the configuration or would Webmin set that up for me (for SSL)?

I used the guide here: https://help.ubuntu.com/10.10/serverguide/C/certificates-and-security.html

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about [`working with a service provider's management interface, such as cPanel`](http://serverfault.com/help/on-topic).

Answer (score 2):

Please follow the steps below:

1.Global configuration > Configure Apache Modules and enable the ssl module

2.If you are just installing one certificate then you would just login to webmin

3.Go to the apache web server

4.Edit the virtual host you are installing it on.

5.Select SSL options and supply the path to the private key and certificate.

6.When you restart apache you might be asked for a certificate pass phrase depending on if you setup a password when generating the csr.

Comment: I don't have an SSL options button in the VirtualHost. I have:

Processes and Limits,
Networking and Addresses, 
MIME Types,
User and Group,  
Miscellaneous,
CGI Programs, 
Per-Directory Options Files,
Configure Apache Modules, 
Edit Defined Parameters, 
Edit Config Files